# Change css on input change

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

**Why does it work with "red"**

```
var inputButtonColor = $('input#button-color');

inputButtonColor.change(function() {
  var inputButtonColorValue = inputButtonColor.val();
  alert(inputButtonColorValue);
  $('input.write-review').css({"background-color": "red" });
});
```

[​http://jsfiddle.net/f4ngg/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/f4ngg/2/)

**And this not with "inputButtonColor.val()"**

```
var inputButtonColor = $('input#button-color');

inputButtonColor.change(function() {
  var inputButtonColorValue = inputButtonColor.val();
  alert(inputButtonColorValue);
  $('input.write-review').css({"background-color": inputButtonColorValue });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f4ngg/1/

Comment: It's treating "inputButtonColor.val()" as a string. Remove the quotes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking color code as an input from text box, and if you want to change it to color, You have to add `#` before color code.

So the code will be :

```
var inputButtonColor = $('input#button-color');

inputButtonColor.change(function() {
  var inputButtonColorValue = inputButtonColor.val();
  alert(inputButtonColorValue);
  $('input.write-review').css({"background-color": "#" + inputButtonColor.val() });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f4ngg/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove your variable outside the double quotes, otherwise it'll be treated as a string. The corrected line:

```
 $('iframe').contents().find('input.write-review').css({"background-color": inputButtonColor.val()});
```

Hope that helped!